# privilege escalation with named pipe in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, privileges

I have this code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <namedpipeapi.h>
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    LPCWSTR pipeName = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\TestSV";
    HANDLE serverPipe;
    int err = 0;
    BOOL isPipeConnected;
    BOOL isPipeOpen;
    DWORD bytesWritten = 0;

    std::wcout << "Creating named pipe " << pipeName << std::endl;
    serverPipe = CreateNamedPipe(pipeName, PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE, 1, 2048, 2048, 0, NULL);

    isPipeConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(serverPipe, NULL);
    if (isPipeConnected) {
        std::wcout << "Incoming connection to " << pipeName << std::endl;
    }

    std::wcout << "Impersonating the client..." << std::endl;
    ImpersonateNamedPipeClient(serverPipe);
    err = GetLastError();
    std::wcout << "Impersonating status..." << err << std::endl;

    STARTUPINFO si = {};
    wchar_t command[] = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";
    std::wcout << command << std::endl;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};
    HANDLE threadToken = GetCurrentThreadToken();
    std::wcout << "Thread token " << threadToken << std::endl;
    CreateProcessWithTokenW(threadToken, LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, command, NULL, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    err = GetLastError();
    std::wcout << "Elv status..." << err << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I create a server pipe and listen for an incoming connection. In my case, I run:

```
cmd.exe /c echo hello > //./pipe/TestSV
```

I am supposed to be able to impersonate the thread token of `cmd.exe` and launch `notepad.exe` as the `SYSTEM` user instead of the local user, however something is not working correctly.

I checked Microsoft documentation, and it states that a successful call to `CreateProcessWithTokenW()` and `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient()` should return a non-zero value. I got large numbers as my return in both cases, so I am kind of confused why it's not working. Am I missing something?

---

**UPDATE**: I updated the code as suggested, but it is still not working correctly, and I get a different error now:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <namedpipeapi.h>
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    LPCWSTR pipeName = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\TestSV";
    LPVOID pipeBuffer = NULL;
    HANDLE serverPipe;
    HANDLE threadToken = NULL;
    DWORD readBytes = 0;
    DWORD readBuffer = 0;
    int err = 0;
    BOOL isPipeConnected;
    BOOL isPipeOpen;
    BYTE bMessage[128] = { 0 };
    DWORD bytesWritten = 0;

    std::wcout << "Creating named pipe " << pipeName << std::endl;
    serverPipe = CreateNamedPipe(pipeName, PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE, 1, 2048, 2048, 0, NULL);

    isPipeConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(serverPipe, NULL);
    if (isPipeConnected) {
        std::wcout << "Incoming connection to " << pipeName << std::endl;
    }

    if (!ReadFile(serverPipe, &bMessage, 1, &bytesWritten, NULL)) {
        std::wcout << "Failed to READ" << std::endl;
    }
        
    
    std::wcout << "Impersonating the client..." << std::endl;
    if (!ImpersonateNamedPipeClient(serverPipe)) {
        err = GetLastError();
        std::wcout << "Impersonating error..." << err << std::endl;
    }

    // get a handle to this threads token
    if (!OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, &threadToken)) {
        err = GetLastError();
        std::wcout << "Token error..." << err << std::endl;
    }
        

    STARTUPINFO si = {};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};
    wchar_t command[] = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";

    
    int process_status = CreateProcessWithTokenW(&threadToken, LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, command, NULL, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    err = GetLastError();
    std::wcout << "Elv error..." << process_status << std::endl;
    std::wcout << "Elv error..." << err << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I found my issue after modifying my output- 1368 (0x558)

Unable to impersonate using a named pipe until data has been read from that pipe.

Comment: It's been a few days, has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are NOT checking the return values of `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient()` and `CreateProcessWithTokenW()` at all (like you do with `ConnectNamedPipe()`). You are checking the return value of `GetLastError()` instead. Not the same thing. `GetLastError()` is meaningless for these functions if they do not return `FALSE` on failure. So, use this instead:

```
if (!ImpersonateNamedPipeClient(serverPipe))
{
    err = GetLastError();
    std::wcout << "Impersonating failed..." << err << std::endl;
}
```

```
if (!CreateProcessWithTokenW(threadToken, LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, command, NULL, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    err = GetLastError();
    std::wcout << "Elv failed..." << err << std::endl;
}
```

That being said, once you have fixed that, you'll notice that `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient()` fails with error `1368` (`ERROR_CANNOT_IMPERSONATE`):

> Unable to impersonate using a named pipe until data has been read from that pipe.

The [`ImpersonateNamedPipeClient()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-impersonatenamedpipeclient) documentation states:

> The ImpersonateNamedPipeClient function allows the server end of a named pipe to impersonate the client end. When this function is called, the named-pipe file system changes the thread of the calling process to start impersonating the security context **of the last message read from the pipe**. Only the server end of the pipe can call this function.

Typically, you would not impersonate a client until after the client has first sent you a request to access something that needs the client's security context.  Read a request, then impersonate if needed, then access whatever is needed, then revert impersonation, and repeat, until the client is disconnected.

So, in your case, read the `hello` input first, then impersonate, then launch `cmd.exe`.

Comment: I changed my code, and I now get "1314 - A required privilege is not held by the client". When I execute "echo" command, I am writing "hello" to the named pipe and I am supposed to impersonate cmd.exe. i don't understand why it's failing

Comment: @DunDmy Next time you "change the code", please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates existing comments/answers.  I have rolled back your edit, and placed the changes at the end of the previous question instead.

Comment: @DunDmy "*I now get 1314*" - WHERE are you getting that error, exactly? You need to be more specific. In any case, I do see you are still checking `GetLastError()` without regard to whether `CreateProcessWithTokenW()` actually failed or not.  You made that change for `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient()` and `OpenThreadToken()`, so why not `CreateProcessWithTokenW()`, too?

Comment: @DunDmy  Also, `CreateProcessWithTokenW(&threadToken, ...)` needs to be `CreateProcessWithTokenW(threadToken, ...)` instead (no `&`).  You should compile with [`STRICT` type checking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/strict-type-checking) enabled to catch mistakes like that at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN for [CreateProcessWithTokenW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithtokenw), the calling process must have `SE_IMPERSONATE_NAME` privilege. This is why you get the error `ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD` (1314), so try to run your code (server pipe) with Administrator.

Again, according to MSDN for [ImpersonateNamedPipeClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-impersonatenamedpipeclient), the thread of the calling process starts impersonating the security context of the last message read from the pipe, or you will get the error `ERROR_CANNOT_IMPERSONATE` (1368).